# Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc

I'm using ffmpeg to get a video file on network .I get the sound live but I it get the video too late. The code I use on the receiver side is:

```
 ffmpeg -i rtsp://10.0.0.1:8554/test1.sdp -acodec copy -vcodec copy /home/sana/lab/mrp/test1.avi
```

The code I use On the sender side is :

```
cvlc -vvv /home/sana/lab/video-server1/1.avi --sout '#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=3000,scale=Auto,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=8000}:rtp{dst=10.0.0.2,port=1234,sdp=rtsp://10.0.0.1:8554/test1.sdp}'
```

the error in the output of the ffmpeg command(on the receiver) is:

```
 [avi @ 0x521ba80] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 196, current: 162; changing to 197. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file
```

the errors in the input of the vlc command(on the sender) is:

```
    [0x7f6070000f58] x264 encoder warning: invalid DTS: PTS is less than DTS

    [0x7f608c0009b8] main input error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 532 ms)
    [0x7f608c0009b8] main input error: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
    .
    .
    [mpeg4 @ 0x7f60700075a0] header damaged
    [0x7f6070000b08] avcodec generic warning: cannot decode one frame (4105 bytes)
    [mpeg4 @ 0x7f60700075a0] header damaged
    [0x7f6070000b08] avcodec generic warning: cannot decode one frame (4078 bytes

)
```

What does this actually mean and what can I do to prevent it from happening?

the ffmpeg version is 4.0-static and vlc version is VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind (revision 2.1.6-0-gea01d28) and ubuntu version is 14.04.